# Yoast SEO Wordpress plugin shows blank page

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone please tell me why my sitemap.xml for the yoast wordpress SEO plugin just shows up with a blank page?

http://alanbrandt.com/sitemap_index.xml

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was related to a conflict with another wordpress plugin "W3 Total Cache"

Deactivate the plugin then deactivate and reactivate the Yoast SEO Wordpress plugin.